# Messages Sent but Never Arrive for Hotmail (probably other Microsoft services)

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I run my own outgoing mail server in order to send e-mail more smoothly for a demanding message board, at least that's the idea.

For most e-mail services it works fine but lately messages being sent to hotmail, and possibly other Microsoft services, are simply disappearing.

They give all the appearance of being sent correctly (logs confirm they're accepted by the target mail server), but they don't show up for the recipient at all. They're not being bounced either, they're simply disappearing, which is pretty bewildering.

I'm running `postfix` with `opendkim` signing the messages and not much else, and I have correctly configured SPF and DMARC DNS records (with the quarantine directive, so messages should at worst be going into spam).

As I say, other recipient services are working just fine, it's only apparently hotmail with which this is happening; I don't have any Outlook or other accounts to check those as well, so I suspect they might be similarly affected.

I'm not currently listed on any blacklists according to mxtoolbox's blacklist tool.

So I'm not sure what else I can try to resolve this; as I say other recipient services deliver without issue, including gmail and others that are quite strict in requiring valid DMARC, DKIM and SPF, so it doesn't seem like a misconfiguration.

Unfortunately I've not yet been able to pinpoint when exactly the issue began, as I don't sent to hotmail myself and users that are affected haven't been able to give me much to work with so far (those who've responded so far don't keep old notification e-mails).

Any my question is this; if other recipients work fine, and I'm not any blacklists, what else could be causing messages to hotmail to simply disappear without bouncing or being junked? Are there any other blacklists I should try (that mxtoolbox doesn't check)?

Comment: "I run my own outgoing mail server in order to send e-mail more smoothly..." Well, there's your problem. If you want smooth e-mail, don't do it yourself. Let Sendgrid, Amazon SES, or one of the many other ESPs do it.

Comment: If your logs show that the email was accepted by the recipient server then the email was accepted by the recipient server. It's in their system. What their system did with it is anybody's guess.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Well, I was hoping someone might have some idea 

I mean, clearly people are getting e-mail delivered, so why aren't mind getting through? Why not even bounced? Is there somewhere I can go to find out more?

I've looked at articles on preventing false positives but they don't seem to identify a specific block-list for Microsoft that might indicate a difference.